# Set Worksheet Name Equal To A Variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I want to be able to open up a second data source (workbook) and select the sheet within the second workbook which is equal to the name in a cell in my first workbook.

So far I have:

```
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim src2 As Workbook
    Dim shtno As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set src = ActiveWorkbook
    shtno = Sheets("CONTROL").Range("G3").Value
    Set ws = Sheets(shtno)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= 'file link
    Set src2 = ActiveWorkbook

    ws.Select
```

Where 'ws.Select' should select my sheet required. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Set ws = src2.Sheets(shtno)`?

Comment: So you open a workbook, and want to select a worksheet within another workbook which is not even the active one? (You see why this is not working?) Can you try to activate that particular workbook and then try to select the worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigBen is correct.

You need to move the `Set ws` statement down **below** the `Workbooks.Open` statement then:

```
Set ws = src2.Sheets(shtno)
ws.Select
```

**NOTE:**

- once you `Open` the new workbook, it becomes the `Active` workbook
- you can only `Select` a worksheet on the `Active` workbook

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but your clarification was really useful. Thanks!